# Spring Security, JDBC, c3p0 connection problem

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-security, c3p0

To improve my skills I've decided to grab an Udemy course about Spring framework. During this course there is a task to create logging into app using JDBC and C3P0.

I've followed all course details and instructor tips. After I deploy my app on Tomcat it is running, but I am unable to log in using the data that has been put in DB. My goal is to log into the app, but for now I am unable to make it. I have even dowloaded solution code, but even after firing it I am unable to log into the further app part.

Whole code structure is good (at least i do believe it). Below I have placed screen and code of most important classes and files.

I have tried to remove {noop} from the DB, but without any result. I have also tried to use an empty line as a password - without any success. When I was doing logging with auth from memory everything was fine, but when i try to parse it from DB i am unable to log in ( there are no error logs, I just got information from app that user and password are wrong.

DemoAppConfig.java

```
package com.luv2code.springsecurity.demo.config;

import java.beans.PropertyVetoException;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

import com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages="com.luv2code.springsecurity.demo")
@PropertySource("classpath:persistence-mysql.properties")
public class DemoAppConfig {

    // set up variable to hold the properties
    
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;
    
    // set up a logger for diagnostics
    
    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName());
    
    
    // define a bean for ViewResolver

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        
        return viewResolver;
    }
    
    // define a bean for our security datasource
    
    @Bean
    public DataSource securityDataSource() {
        
        // create connection pool
        ComboPooledDataSource securityDataSource
                                    = new ComboPooledDataSource();
                
        // set the jdbc driver class
        
        try {
            securityDataSource.setDriverClass(env.getProperty("jdbc.driver"));
        } catch (PropertyVetoException exc) {
            throw new RuntimeException(exc);
        }
        
        // log the connection props
        // for sanity's sake, log this info
        // just to make sure we are REALLY reading data from properties file
        
        logger.info(">>> jdbc.url=" + env.getProperty("jdbc.url"));
        logger.info(">>> jdbc.user=" + env.getProperty("jdbc.user"));
        
        
        // set database connection props
        
        securityDataSource.setJdbcUrl(env.getProperty("jdbc.url"));
        securityDataSource.setUser(env.getProperty("jdbc.user"));
        securityDataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("jdbc.password"));
        
        // set connection pool props
        
        securityDataSource.setInitialPoolSize(
                getIntProperty("connection.pool.initialPoolSize"));

        securityDataSource.setMinPoolSize(
                getIntProperty("connection.pool.minPoolSize"));

        securityDataSource.setMaxPoolSize(
                getIntProperty("connection.pool.maxPoolSize"));

        securityDataSource.setMaxIdleTime(
                getIntProperty("connection.pool.maxIdleTime"));
        
        return securityDataSource;
    }
    
    // need a helper method 
    // read environment property and convert to int
    
    private int getIntProperty(String propName) {
        
        String propVal = env.getProperty(propName);
        
        // now convert to int
        int intPropVal = Integer.parseInt(propVal);
        
        return intPropVal;
    }
}
```

DemoSecurityConfig.java

```
package com.luv2code.springsecurity.demo.config;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User.UserBuilder;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class DemoSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    // add a reference to our security data source
    
    @Autowired
    private DataSource securityDataSource;
    
    
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        // use jdbc authentication ... oh yeah!!!
        
        auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(securityDataSource);
        
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/").hasRole("EMPLOYEE")
            .antMatchers("/leaders/**").hasRole("MANAGER")
            .antMatchers("/systems/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/showMyLoginPage")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/authenticateTheUser")
                .permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout().permitAll()
            .and()
            .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/access-denied");
        
    }
        
}
```

MySpringMvcDispatcherServletInitializer.java

```
package com.luv2code.springsecurity.demo.config;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class MySpringMvcDispatcherServletInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { DemoAppConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

}
```

persistence-mysql.properties

```
#
# JDBC connection properties
#
jdbc.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/spring_security_demo_plaintext?useSSL=false
jdbc.user=hbstudent
jdbc.password=hbstudent

#
# Connection pool properties
#
connection.pool.initialPoolSize=5
connection.pool.minPoolSize=5
connection.pool.maxPoolSize=20
connection.pool.maxIdleTime=3000
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.luv2code</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-demo</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>spring-security-demo</name>

    <properties>
        <springframework.version>5.0.2.RELEASE</springframework.version>
        <springsecurity.version>5.0.0.RELEASE</springsecurity.version>

        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- Spring MVC support -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Security -->
        <!-- spring-security-web and spring-security-config -->
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${springsecurity.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${springsecurity.version}</version>
        </dependency>   
        
        <!-- Add Spring Security Taglibs support -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
            <version>${springsecurity.version}</version>
        </dependency>   
        
        <!-- Add MySQL and C3P0 support -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.45</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
            <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
                
        
        <!-- Servlet, JSP and JSTL support -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <!-- TO DO: Add support for Maven WAR Plugin -->

    <build>
        <finalName>spring-security-demo</finalName>
    
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <!-- Add Maven coordinates (GAV) for: maven-war-plugin -->
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2.0</version>                    
                </plugin>                       
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>


</project>
```

SQL code responsible for generating DB test data

```
DROP DATABASE  IF EXISTS `spring_security_demo_plaintext`;

CREATE DATABASE  IF NOT EXISTS `spring_security_demo_plaintext`;
USE `spring_security_demo_plaintext`;

--
-- Table structure for table `users`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `users`;
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `username` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `enabled` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`username`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Inserting data for table `users`
--

INSERT INTO `users` 
VALUES 
('john','{noop}test123',1),
('mary','{noop}test123',1),
('susan','{noop}test123',1);


--
-- Table structure for table `authorities`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `authorities`;
CREATE TABLE `authorities` (
  `username` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `authority` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `authorities_idx_1` (`username`,`authority`),
  CONSTRAINT `authorities_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`username`) REFERENCES `users` (`username`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Inserting data for table `authorities`
--

INSERT INTO `authorities` 
VALUES 
('john','ROLE_EMPLOYEE'),
('mary','ROLE_EMPLOYEE'),
('mary','ROLE_MANAGER'),
('susan','ROLE_EMPLOYEE'),
('susan','ROLE_ADMIN');
```

Answer (score 0):

Type it as below:

```
username = "john"
password = "{noop}test123"
```

yes, exactly same password shown in the database, need to include the `{noop}` also for the password.